Function does not run as result of a Browser.msgBox prompt response
I have a big red button in my google sheet that has "Clear Notes" written on it, and I have it attached to a function called "ClearCells." This ClearCells function was the first AppScript I set up, which worked perfectly fine. Then I needed to set up a prompt pop up that would confirm if the user actually meant to click the button, or if it was a mistake. I need the ClearCells function to run only when the response to the Browser.msgBox prompt is "yes", and to not run the function when the response is "no" or if the prompt is closed using the close button.
Below is the AppScript I have so far. Currently when I click on the "Clear Notes" button, it returns with the error message: "Script function ClearCells could not be found."
var response = Browser.msgBox('One Second!', 'This will delete all weekly notes. Are you sure?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
if (response=='yes') {
  function ClearCells() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ExampleSheet1');
    sheet.getRange('D3:D').clearContent();}
} else {
  Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
}

I tried creating another AppScript project that contains JUST the ClearCells function, and having both projects actually makes the button click proceed to the Browser.msgBox prompt. But the problem is that it runs the function, regardless of whether I click yes or no.

The problem is that the function declaration is not on the top level.
On the other hand, it's unclear if the code included in the question is at the top level or inside the function declaration block.
To fix the error, move the clearCells function to the top level. You should see this function name in the Google Apps Script Editor toolbar dropdown. See the below image:


Hi, thank you for the response! I'm not sure if I understood what you meant by "move the clearCells function to the top level." Does that mean it should have the function declared first at the top of the AppScript, above the Browser.msgBox section? Now my AppScript starts with the function declaration on line 1, and the original "var response = Browser.msgBox" code follows on line 5. I just tried the button again, and it still runs the function regardless of the user response to the msgbox prompt.

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as the programming language. Please consider spending some time learning the basics of JavaScript. This will help to reduce the back and forth when asking for help on issues with Google Apps Script. Once said that, please post your follow-up question as a new question including a [mcve].
